# SQLAlchemy column name and property conflict

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table schema "project_table" with a column named "status".
The problem is, I would like to override and wrap the "status" column with project.status property that will wrap Status('str') for convenience for other cases not showing here.

Basically I would like to do this:

```
project = Session().query( Project ).filter_by( id=ID ).one()
print project.status #> will give <Status('act')> and not 'act'
```

But since the Column('status') already create a 'status' attribute, I can't override it nicely. So I wander how I can do that cleanly?
cleanly to me means without tweaking the column or attribute name ( Column('status_') or project.status_ )

```
# Import
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, Column, String, Enum, Integer

project_table   = Table('project', metadata,
                    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                    Column('name', String(32), nullable=False),
                    Column('status', Enum(u'act', u'dis'), default=u'act'))

metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base()

# Project ORM class
class Project(Base):
    __table__ = project_table

    def __init__(self, **columns):
        super(Project, self).__init__(**columns)

    @property
    def status(self):
        '''Return status instance
        '''
        if not hasattr(self, '__status'):
            self.__status = Status(self.status)
        return self.__status

# Status wrapper class
class Status(str):
    '''Status layer of friendliness.
    '''

    MAP  = {'act'   : 'active',
            'dis'   : 'disabled' }

    def __init__(self, status_str ):

        self.__status   = status_str
        self.__nicename = ''
        self.__codename = ''

        for nicename, codename in Status.MAP.iteritems():

            if self.__status in [ nicename, codename ]:
                self.__nicename = nicename
                self.__codename = codename

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.__status == other:
            return True
        elif self.nicename() == other:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def nicename(self):
        '''Return full name.
        '''
        return self.__nicename

    def codename(self):
        '''Return short/code name.
        '''
        return self.__codename
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [hybrid attributes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/hybrid.html), which may do what you want, but honestly, hiding the column name like this is not "clean" or good coding practice. It's confusing.

My $0.02 is just rename the column or rename the attribute you're trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could use Sql Alchemy's '[reconstructor](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapper_config.html#constructors-and-object-initialization)' to set your default as the object is loaded from the DB.

```
from sqlalchemy import orm

class Project(Base):
        __table__ = project_table

        def __init__(self, **columns):
            super(Project, self).__init__(**columns)

        @orm.reconstructor
        def init_on_load(self):
            # set status defaults here
```